# Please let me know how to pass the values as 3 level in constructors in java?

Tags: java, constructor

This is my main function.

```
class first{
  public static void main(String ar[]){
    second sc = new second();
  }
}

class second{
  second(third th){
    this.th = th;
  }
}


class third{
  private int i;
  third(int i){
    this.i = i;
  }
}
```

Please tell me solution without changing the constructor arguments. I am not getting how to pass constructor and how the arguments of constructor is given as the object of classes.

Comment: without changing the constructor argument, it will never work

Answer (score 1):

Call the constructor in the argument to the constructor for `second` (or first create a variable and pass that)

```
second sec = new second(new third(12));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `second` constructor requires an instance of `third` class:

```
third th = new third(10);
second sc = new second(th);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class first{
  public static void main(String ar[]){
    third third= new third(1);// make third type variable and pass this
    second sc = new second(third);
  }
}

class second{
  private third th; // Need to define this
  second(third th){
    this.th = th;
  }
}


class third{
  private int i;
  third(int i){
    this.i = i;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I call methods of third class in first class?

Comment: @YashChoksi you can use all public methods by third variable .